# Why does React App appear twice on webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I created a React app based on Free Code Camp's Drum Machine project which works successfully on Code Pen and passes all tests found here https://codepen.io/kevin-orara/pen/RwKvjJz however when I transfer the code to Visual Studio it now fails 1 test. Yes the app appears to work and even compiled successfully. Now it is failing one test which is #6

> When I press the trigger key associated with each .drum-pad, the audio clip contained in its child  element should be triggered (e.g. pressing the Q key should trigger the drum pad which contains the string "Q", pressing the W key should trigger the drum pad which contains the string "W", etc.).

GitHub Repo here: https://github.com/korara78/drum-machine-fcc/tree/main/drum-machine-fcc

There are two things I noticed which seemed odd. First I had to add this code to the index.html file just to get the code to compile successfully. Being new to creating React apps I've only had to add 1 div id on index.html files thus far.

```
<div id="drum-machine" class="container"></div>
<div id='root'></div>
```

In response I tried altering the import/export scripts on the index.js and App.js files but the current code is the best I could produce to even get the app working/compiled successfully.

Second, I noticed that the app appears "twice" on the App site published via GitHub Pages here https://korara78.github.io/drum-machine-fcc/  It appears twice as you scroll down on the page.

Any suggestions or assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `ReactDOM.render(<App />, ...);` multiple times, once in [App.js](https://github.com/korara78/drum-machine-fcc/blob/67a72f9be4301a69d44a16ec8cf3303ca401e9df/drum-machine-fcc/src/App.js#L107) and again in [index.js](https://github.com/korara78/drum-machine-fcc/blob/67a72f9be4301a69d44a16ec8cf3303ca401e9df/drum-machine-fcc/src/index.js#L8:L13). Calling render twice will cause two versions to appear.

App.js:

```js
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('drum-machine'));
```

index.js

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Remove the one in `App.js`, and change in the in `index.js` to be the `#drum-machine` `<div>` if you wish.

`index.js` is where `ReactDOM.render(...)` should be called, `App.js` is where you should define the `App` component.

Comment: Thank you for reviewing my inquiry and problem. Your explanation was very clear. I removed the ReactDOM.render(...) from the App.js and retained it in index.js as you had advised. Then I updated the index.js to include ('drum-machine'). I made these updates locally to test and the app was fixed.  I then deployed and pushed updates to the respective GH-pages site and it looks good there too. Greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `React.StrictMode` tag. Just comment it out, and `<App />` will run only once. I do not know why or how it works, but it has solved my issue.
This is how 'index.js' should look like:

```js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    // <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
    // </React.StrictMode>
);
```